# What is the significance of ":" in getopt_long function?

Tags: c

In the `getopt_long` example [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Option-Example.html), why are the short options separated by a colon at `abc:d:f:` and why are `abc` are grouped together like that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>

/* Flag set by ‘--verbose’. */
static int verbose_flag;

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int c;

  while (1)
    {
      static struct option long_options[] =
        {
          /* These options set a flag. */
          {"verbose", no_argument,       &verbose_flag, 1},
          {"brief",   no_argument,       &verbose_flag, 0},
          /* These options don’t set a flag.
             We distinguish them by their indices. */
          {"add",     no_argument,       0, 'a'},
          {"append",  no_argument,       0, 'b'},
          {"delete",  required_argument, 0, 'd'},
          {"create",  required_argument, 0, 'c'},
          {"file",    required_argument, 0, 'f'},
          {0, 0, 0, 0}
        };
      /* getopt_long stores the option index here. */
      int option_index = 0;

      c = getopt_long (argc, argv, "abc:d:f:",
                       long_options, &option_index);

      /* Detect the end of the options. */
      if (c == -1)
        break;

      switch (c)
        {
        case 0:
          /* If this option set a flag, do nothing else now. */
          if (long_options[option_index].flag != 0)
            break;
          printf ("option %s", long_options[option_index].name);
          if (optarg)
            printf (" with arg %s", optarg);
          printf ("\n");
          break;

        case 'a':
          puts ("option -a\n");
          break;

        case 'b':
          puts ("option -b\n");
          break;

        case 'c':
          printf ("option -c with value `%s'\n", optarg);
          break;

        case 'd':
          printf ("option -d with value `%s'\n", optarg);
          break;

        case 'f':
          printf ("option -f with value `%s'\n", optarg);
          break;

        case '?':
          /* getopt_long already printed an error message. */
          break;

        default:
          abort ();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but you link to the example in the `getopt_long` *documentation*? The documentation which will contain the answer to your question.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't read the documentation properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[On GNU's page](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html), it is said that

> An option character in this string can be followed by a colon (`:`) to
> indicate that it takes a required argument.

For example, `xy:zq` accepts the options `x`, `y`, `z`, `q`; `y` requires an additional argument.

Comment: I didn't read the doc properly, sorry. For clarification, `y` requires an additional argument means? From the doc you linked, what I understood is that y is a required argument. The grouping is just because of the ordering of the arguments in the string.

Comment: @kovac For example you run your execution `./kovac.out -q -x -y "my_req_argument"`

Comment: Oh, understood. So, `q` and `x` may be for setting a flag, but `y` requires a value. Thank you!

Comment: @kovac you can even watch from here https://youtu.be/HeNqqsGxM4k?t=78 how he uses -x argument